# win32.client com_error "Array index out of bounds"

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I have a short function that compiles a list of all the emails in a specific outlook folder and then saves the attachments to a specific folder. I last used this function successfully about 3 months ago and it seems something has broken it.

The exception:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Array index out of bounds.', None, 0, -2147352567), None)
```

I'm not familiar enough with win32.com to understand what it's trying to tell me and it's a difficult error to get information on since it seems there can be many causes. I've marked in the function where it occurs.

It runs just fine for about 5,000 emails. There are about 1,000 attachments out of 6,500 that I can't download.

```
def outlook_attachments() -> None:
    files_list = glob.glob('sort_test/*.txt')
    files_list = [x[11:] for x in files_list]
    # Connect to outlook.
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    # Navigate to the Oasis folder.
    oasis_folder = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(4).folders("Oasis")
    # Define items inside Oasis folder.
    messages = oasis_folder.Items
    # Start reading messages in Oasis folder, start from 0.
    message = messages.GetFirst()
    # Defining path to save attachment to.
    path = 'fxg-notebooks/sort_test/'
    # Iterating through all Oasis messages, saving files that have not yet been saved.
    new_file_count = 0
    message_count = 0

    while True:
        # print('Messages processed: ', message_count, end='\r')
        message_count += 1
        # Read attachment from outlook message.
        try:
            attachment = message.Attachments.Item(1) <--- EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE
        # If GetNext() returned None, all messages have been read, break loop.
        except AttributeError:
            break
        # Check for attachment membership in files_list.
        try:
            if files_list.index(str(attachment)) >= 0:
                message = messages.GetNext()
                continue
        # If no membership, save attachment.
        except ValueError:
            attachment.SaveASFile(path + str(attachment))
            message = messages.GetNext()
            new_file_count += 1

    return None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is assuming there is at least one attachment in the message. Check that `message.Attachments.Count > 0` first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm implementing it now.

Comment: I'm not sure why it helped because all emails going to this folder will have an attachment. Anyway, I got a new error. Not sure why it's saying I don't have permission, if I run the function on a folder with no attachments in it I can save about 5.5k attachments with no problem. new error: com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', "Cannot save the attachment. You don't have appropriate permission to perform this operation.", None, 0, -2147024891), None)

Comment: What are the values of `path` and 'str(attachment)'? the error most likely means what it says - you do not have write access to teh folder where you are trying to save the attachment.

Comment: Also, replace `str(attachment)` with `attachment.FileName`

Comment: path is OS path to folder. I'm not sure what cause the permission error or how I fixed it but it's gone. I was able to get about 800 more attachments with your message.Attachments count check, but I'm still short. I think I will consider this issue closed since the new problem is completely different.

Comment: You might also want to check `attachment.Type` property to be 1 (`OlAttachmentType.olByValue`) - OLE attachments etc. might have `Filename` = "", and your code will fail in that case with the exact error you are seeing when you try to save attachment specifying `path` only.